# Python: how to add first value in each list

Tags: python, list

A Posn is a list of length two `[x,y]`, where
 `x` and `y` are both `Float` values, corresponding to 
 the `x` and `y` coordinates of the point, respectively.

```
 make_posn: float float -> Posn
def make_posn(x_coord, y_coord):
    return [x_coord, y_coord]
```

How do I add all the x-values in a list of Posns?

Ex: `[ [3.0, 4.0], [8.0, -1.0], [0.0, 2.0]]` would be `11`

Comment: Is the first line of code a comment?

Answer (score 2):

[`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#sum) them:

```
In [2]: sum(x[0] for x in [ [3.0, 4.0], [8.0, -1.0], [0.0, 2.0]])
Out[2]: 11.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The following piece of code should work for your

```
_sum = 0.0
for sublist in [ [3.0, 4.0], [8.0, -1.0], [0.0, 2.0]]:
    _sum += sublist[0]
```

It initializes a sum accumulator to zero and then iterates over the sublist elements of the list to add the value of the first element of each list, to the initial sum

Comment: `sum` is a Python builtin. Don't overwrite it.

Comment: Now use a generator and the `sum` builtin. Your code is not done in Python style.